# How to adjust radius size when plotting circular graph with networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I need to plot several circular graphs in a figure having multiple rows and columns. A simple example is given by the following, where I create a subplot with 2 rows and 2 columns. Each entry contains a circle graph having 10, 6, 8, and 8 nodes, respectively.

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8,8)

n1=10
labels1={k:str(k) for k in range(n1)}
G1=nx.Graph()
G1.add_nodes_from(range(n1))

n2=6
labels2={k:str(k) for k in range(n2)}
G2=nx.Graph()
G2.add_nodes_from(range(n2))

n3=8
labels3={k:str(k) for k in range(n3)}
G3=nx.Graph()
G3.add_nodes_from(range(n3))

n4=8
labels4={k:str(k) for k in range(n4)}
G4=nx.Graph()
G4.add_nodes_from(range(n4))

fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,2)
node_size=250

nx.draw_circular(G1,labels=labels1,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[0,0],node_color='red')
nx.draw_circular(G2,labels=labels2,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[0,1],node_color='gray')
nx.draw_circular(G3,labels=labels3,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[1,0],node_color='yellow')
 nx.draw_circular(G4,labels=labels4,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[1,1],node_color='cyan')

plt.show()
```

The resulting figure is given below. How can I shrink the radii of the circles, which will be useful when I add several more rows and/or columns to my subplots??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `nx.draw_circular`, you can use `nx.draw` with the node positions set with `nx.circular_layout`. You can then adjust the radius of `nx.circular_layout` by changing the `scale` argument. Finally, when you call `plt.subplots`, you should change `sharex` and `sharey` to `True` to make sure that the subplots have the same `y` and `x` limits.

See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8,8)

n1=10
labels1={k:str(k) for k in range(n1)}
G1=nx.Graph()
G1.add_nodes_from(range(n1))

n2=6
labels2={k:str(k) for k in range(n2)}
G2=nx.Graph()
G2.add_nodes_from(range(n2))

n3=8
labels3={k:str(k) for k in range(n3)}
G3=nx.Graph()
G3.add_nodes_from(range(n3))

n4=8
labels4={k:str(k) for k in range(n4)}
G4=nx.Graph()
G4.add_nodes_from(range(n4))

fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=True, sharey=True)
node_size=250

nx.draw(G1,pos=nx.circular_layout(G1,scale=0.2),labels=labels1,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[0,0],node_color='red')
nx.draw(G2,pos=nx.circular_layout(G2,scale=0.4),labels=labels2,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[0,1],node_color='gray')
nx.draw(G3,pos=nx.circular_layout(G3,scale=0.6),labels=labels3,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[1,0],node_color='yellow')
nx.draw(G4,pos=nx.circular_layout(G4,scale=0.8),labels=labels4,node_size=node_size,ax=ax[1,1],node_color='cyan')

plt.show()
```

And the output:

[image]